# In Unity 2021.x.x I cannot change value of array item of scriptableobject on Editor Window

Tags: unity, c#

[image]

So in Unity 2021.x.x I cannot change value of array item but on 2020.x.x it can change. Below the simple example to explain the problem, I can add an item of `listChildren` but I cannot add an item of `children`. Also I cannot edit string of `testString`

```csharp
[System.Serializable]
public class Test
{
    public string testString;
    public List<GameObject> children;
}

public class BaseResources : ScriptableObject
{

}

public class SimpleTest : BaseResources
{
    public List<Test> listChildren;
}
```

This is my editor window

```
public class ResourcesEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    protected SerializedObject serializedObject;
    protected SerializedProperty serializedProperty;
    private BaseResources[] resources;
    protected string selectedPropertyPach;
    protected string selectedProperty;

    [MenuItem("Window/Resources")]
    static void Init()
    {
        // Get existing open window or if none, make a new one:
        EditorWindow window = GetWindow(typeof(ResourcesEditorWindow));
        window.Show();

    }

    protected virtual void OnGUI()
    {
        resources = GetAllInstances<BaseResources>();
        serializedObject = new SerializedObject(resources[0]);

        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical("box", GUILayout.MaxWidth(150), GUILayout.ExpandHeight(true));

        DrawSliderBar(resources);

        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical("box", GUILayout.ExpandHeight(true));

        if (selectedProperty != null)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < resources.Length; i++)
            {
                if (resources[i].name == selectedProperty)
                {
                    serializedObject = new SerializedObject(resources[i]);
                    serializedProperty = serializedObject.GetIterator();
                    serializedProperty.NextVisible(true);
                    DrawProperties(serializedProperty);

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("select an item from the list");
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        Apply();


    }

    protected void DrawProperties(SerializedProperty property)
    {
        while (property.NextVisible(false))
        {
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(property, true);
        }
    }


    public static T[] GetAllInstances<T>() where T : BaseResources
    {
        string[] guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:" + typeof(T).Name);
        T[] a = new T[guids.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < guids.Length; i++)
        {
            string path = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guids[i]);
            a[i] = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<T>(path);
        }

        return a;

    }



    protected void DrawSliderBar(BaseResources[] prop)
    {
        foreach (BaseResources p in prop)
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button(p.name))
            {
                selectedPropertyPach = p.name;
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedPropertyPach))
        {
            selectedProperty = selectedPropertyPach;
        }

    }

    protected void Apply()
    {
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have read somewhere that Unity move all editor UI from UGUI to UIToolkit. Which make reorderable list not supported when using OnGUI(). You can use UIToolkit to make editor and it's less codes than using UGUI.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/107910)

Comment: I don't think this is a fundamental limitation of the engine version, but an error in your code that's preventing the size change from being detected/serialized. Previous versions of the engine may simply have been more tolerant of this error (so you may be a victim of Hyrum's Law - depending on an observable behaviour of the engine's API that was not part of its official contract, and so subject to change between versions).